# which L1 blockchains are truly modular blockchains?

Tags: rollups, modular-blockchains, cosmos

I want to know which blockchains are modular blockchains.

I know about cosmos and Celestia, and I guess they are L1 modular blockchains, also I know that rollups are L2/Ln modular blockchains.

But tell precisely that which blockchains are really modular blockchains /